# VBA Browse and Select

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Private Sub bBrowse_Click()

  Const msoFileDialogFilePicker As Long = 3
Dim objDialog As Object

Set objDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

With objDialog
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No file selected."
    Else
        Me.[File Link].Value = Dir(.SelectedItems(1))
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

I was able to get it to add in the cell I need it to but it when it is clicked it will not open the file or path

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9476268/filedialog-doesnt-work?answertab=oldest#comment17467925_9476268  I am using this code but I need to add the full path to the file

Comment: [ask] -- please explain what you want to do, and what exactly doesn't work.

Comment: Hi Andre, I am trying to link a file into a shared drive. Once it is added to the record. Another person can click the link and open the file. I can not use attachments due to the quantity of items that will come through. It shows the file name at the moment but I can not open it. I think it is adding only the file name and not the path.

Comment: For future questions: don't add relevant information in comments, edit your post instead and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this: [Debugging VBA Code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)
to learn how to step through code and inspect variables.

`.SelectedItems(1)` already contains the full path, but `Dir(.SelectedItems(1))` returns only the file name. So remove the `Dir()`.

Now to actually open the file from a record, you need additional code e.g. in a button next to the `File Link` textbox, or in its DblClick event.

See here: [Open Hyperlinks in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010678/open-hyperlinks-in-access)