# Run Time Error '15' - Can not open the specified file (Application.followhyperlink) -

Tags: vba, windows, ms-access, microsoft-edge

I am trying to trace down a runtime error that is happening to a few team members while attempting to open a PDF file link from Access. The VBA code is using an Application.followhyperlink to pass a hyperlink to our SSRS report server. The VBA code correctly passes the URL (it works on my machine) which opens a dialogue box (Microsoft Office) asking the user if they,  "Would like to open this file?". What is supposed to happen is that a web browser opens with the link (and then the PDF file opens from it), but instead the code breaks with the error message of: Run Time Error '15' - Can not open the specified file.

It feels like the issue is with the web browser security (or windows) security.

We are running Microsoft Edge as the default browser. I have tried to play with the security settings with no luck.

Anyone else experience this or have a solution?

Thank you, Brent

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Open Hyperlinks in Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32010678/open-hyperlinks-in-access)

Comment: Or a shorter variant here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40462913/3820271

Comment: I read both of those earlier and they are similar, but I am trying to rule out stuff like browser settings or other window security methods before I tear apart the entire subroutine as I know it will be about other bugs and fixes too. Thanks

Comment: Our IT department updated the user's browser (edge) and it resolved the issue. I also tested the code in the links provide and it also worked.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our IT department updated the user's browser (edge) and it resolved the issue. I also tested the code in the links provide and it also worked. Thank you!